# Convert Sbyte to integer in c#

Tags: c#

I can't seem to figure out a way to convert an sbyte back to original integer value.

```
int k = 148;
sbyte t = (sbyte)k;
int asd = Convert.ToInt32(t);
```

The value of asd is -108. How can I convert the sbyte back to int to get the original value of 148?

Thanks

Comment: I just added k variable for illustration purpose. I don't have access to k, but I have access to t and I would like to somehow convert t back to int.

Comment: Well it *is* converting `t` back to `int`. But given that there are only 256 possible values of `t` but 2^32 possible original values of `k`, you can't do that in a lossless way... Do you know that `k` is always between 0 and 255 inclusive to start with? If so, why are you using `sbyte`?

Comment: Yes k is always between 0 and 255.  sbyte is whats returned by the function and I can't really change it.

Comment: And you're sure that `t` will never *actually* have a value of -108?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the result to be in the range 0-255 inclusive, the simplest approach is:

```
int asd = t & 0xff;
```

This will promote `k` to an `int`, then take just the bottom 8 bits, leaving all the top 24 bits as 0.

However, I'd question why you'd *want* to use `sbyte` for this in the first place. It's very *very* rarely a good idea - one of the design flaws of Java (in my view) was to make `byte` a signed type. If you want to represent byte values, `byte` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but unfortunately I don't have an option to change whats being returned by a particular function.

Comment: @Jon: instead of `int asd = k & 0xff;` shouldn't it be `int asd = t & 0xff;`

Answer (score 1):

As sbyte is in range -128 to 127, ideally your existing method should not return sbyte when the return value can be between 0-255.

But anyway, you can first try converting `sbyte` into `byte` and then into `int`.

I suppose [following code should work](http://ideone.com/0bBORo)

```
int k = 148;
sbyte t = (sbyte)k;
byte b=(byte)t;

Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.WriteLine();

int asd = Convert.ToInt32(b);       
Console.WriteLine(asd);
```

Answer (score 0):

An sbyte holds values from -128 to 127 because the first bit represents plus or minus.
Cast your sbyte to byte first, then convert to int.

```
        int k = 148;
        sbyte t = (sbyte)k;
        int asd = (int)(byte)k;
        Assert.AreEqual(148, asd);
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading info. Please see my above my comment.